# Get Visual Format String from NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: swift, autolayout

Is there a way to get the visual format string from a constraint? I would like to run some tests on generated constraints created using the VFL.

Comment: I guess it is not possible. Because visual format language produces multiple constraints

Comment: When the constraint is logged it shows the string for each. Guess its a combination of properties in the description method.